# Proper usage of Is + Past Participle

Tags: past-tense, adjectives

Is this sentence grammatical?

> The link is commented.

This sound ungrammatical to my ear for some reason. While the following sentence doesn't:

> The link is suspended.

I guess the effect has something to do with some of these:

1. The construction of is + past participle being ambiguous (adjective or passive form of the verb)
2. The words being transitive/intransitive (but here both commented and suspended have both transitive and intransitive forms).
3. Some adjectives cannot act predicatively. (Maybe 'commented' is one of these)
   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39655/adjectives-that-do-not-have-predicative-position

I can't seem to put my finger on exactly what the issue here is. Can somebody help?

Comment: You can suspend a link, but you can only comment _on_ it.

Comment: @KateBunting Is it one of those cases that's mentioned here? https://english.stackexchange.com/a/39656/404512 
The thing is if someone says just that "the link is commented" on an Instagram post. It could mean the link is commented by him below the post, but also that it is a commented-link (which is a far-fetch that doesn't really make much sense, still there's ambiguity). If he had added "below" at the end I think the interpretation would be limited to just the verb, resolving the ambiguity. Is it the ambiguity causing the issue here or is it that some verbs cannot be used predicatively?

Comment: The link _has been_ suspended - it is in the 'suspended' state - but you can't say 'the link has been commented'. Or maybe they do on Instagram? - I've never looked at it. It would be more correct to say 'The link has been commented on' or 'Someone has commented on the link'.

Comment: @KateBunting Although it's not in common usage, I think it's possible to have a link that's in a 'commented' state.

Comment: Not only is this vague, but it's also nonstandard, and illogical. People **post** links, and **comment on** posts, or messages, or threads. Links do not have **commented** as a state, either from a front-end perspective or from a conceptual perspective. It's not in common usage because it's wrong, and a few people misusing words does not make their usage acceptable.

Comment: Tangent, did you read this somewhere or come up with the sentence yourself? Some context on how it was used would help. I can see this being a novel usage of "comment"  given how emerging technology allows words to develop new grammar rules.

Comment: @gotube Thanks, I guess so too. I read this in a post someone made recently, he was trying to say that he has commented the link in the comment box he was referring to in the post. He basically typed "Link is commented" in the post, I felt the sentence as ungrammatical but I wasn't able to figure out what the issue was.

Comment: Sounds to me like a novel usage, which means you won't get a definitive answer here, and maybe that's good enough. To ***comment on** a post* means to say something about the post, perhaps out loud, perhaps in an actual comment box. To ***comment** a post*, I would understand to specifically mean adding a comment in a comment box.